# See amount of memory a pbs job is currently using

Tags: pbs

I know I can see how much memory a pbs job has requested using qstat but is there a way to view how much memory the job is currently using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`qstat -f <jobid>` should show you up-to-date information on the memory usage of your job